# return or send variable to onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve the same functionality of a function from two separate events. So the function I created is:

```
function adding_stuff() {
    var names = [];
    var dates = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        //adding stuff to names and dates
    }
    $(".primary .panel-content").append("<ul class='list-unstyled'></ul>");
    for(var i in names) {
        var li = "<li>";
        $(".primary .panel-content ul").append(li.concat(names[i]))
    }
}
```

There are two buttons `primary` and `secondary`. I want the same functionality for both the functions but the output in different `<div>`. Currently the selected `<div>` is `".primary"`, however I want this to depend on the button which has been clicked.

The function is triggered using:

```
$("#primary").onchange = adding_stuff;
$("#secondary").onchange = adding_stuff;
```

**NOTE:** `primary` and `secondary` are inputs of type `file`.

Comment: how are you _really_ binding the events?  The `.onchange` syntax you've shown isn't legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional data when you register the callback, which will be made available within the event handler:

```
$('#primary').on('change', { target: '.primary' }, adding_stuff);
$('#secondary').on('change', { target: '.secondary' }, adding_stuff);
```

and then within the handler:

```
function adding_stuff(ev) {
    var cls = ev.data.target;  // extract the passed data
    ...
    // file handling code omitted

    $(".panel-content", cls).append(...)
}
```

Comment: This seems to partially work as its not throwing any errors, but `cls` is a nested `div class`, so it needs to come before the `".panel-content"`. Currently, this does not seem to be working at all as nothing is appended.

Comment: @Namit `$('sel', cls)` is the same as `$(cls).find('sel')` which is the same as `$(cls + ' sel')`, so this _should_ be fine.

Answer (score 2):

using jquery's `change()` event

```
function adding_stuff(obj,objClass) {
var names = [];
var dates = [];
for(var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
  //adding stuff to names and dates
}
$("."+ objClass+" .panel-content").append("<ul class='list-unstyled'></ul>");
for(var i in names) {
    var li = "<li>";
    $("."+ objClass+" .panel-content ul").append(li.concat(names[i]))
}
}

$("#primary").change(function(){
   adding_stuff(this,'primary');
});
$("#secondary").change(function(){
    adding_stuff(this,'secondary');
});
```

Comment: This, still throws an error on `files.length`. The primary and secondary are `input` of type `file`.

Comment: this fails because it doesn't preserve the `this` that was passed by jquery into the (anonymous) callbacks when they call `adding_stuff`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).attr("class")` inside the function. It will return the class of button who triggered the event.

```
function adding_stuff() {
var div = $(this).attr("class");
var names = [];
var dates = [];
for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    //adding stuff to names and dates to $div
}
$(div + " .panel-content").append("<ul class='list-unstyled'></ul>");
for(var i in names) {
    var li = "<li>";
    $(div + " .panel-content ul").append(li.concat(names[i]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function adding_stuff(opselector) {
    return function() {
        var names = [];
        var dates = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            // adding stuff to names and dates
        }
        var ul = $("<ul class='list-unstyled'></ul>").appendTo(opselector)
        for (var i in names) {
            ul.append("<li>" + li.concat(names[i]) + "</li>")
        }
    }
}

$("#primary").change(adding_stuff('.primary .panel-content'));
$("#secondary").change(adding_stuff('.secondary .panel-content'));
```

Comment: needlessly complicated - `.on` supports passing element specific parameters directly, no need to return a function.

Comment: I get an error on `this.files.length` saying `length` is undefined. However, this does not happen when nothing is passed in the function.

Comment: @Namit that sounds like you have an unrelated error somewhere else in your code

Comment: @Namit what is primary and secondary

Comment: I've updated by question with the information on the buttons, they are `<input type='file' id='primary'` etc.

Comment: `this` has to be set as a closure variable in the scope of `add_stuff`